# clipper question with non-ideal diodes

Tags: diodes, signal, voltage-clipping

Vo for the clipper  circuit where Vi = 10sin (6280t) and diodes are 0.6 volts.
[image]

I think the simple form of the circuit is like this.
[image]

if we don't calculate the resistors. Could the output signal be this way?[image]

Comment: In your 'simple' circuit Vo = Vi, no matter what is between them. It's not at all like the original.

Comment: IN your hand drawn schematic Vo = Vi. The diodes and resistors don't do anything.

Comment: can you help for the truth?

Comment: @safak26 More like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEsx7.png), perhaps?

Comment: @safak26 You should be able to just look at it and work out the output. When the signal goes high, it has to drop through one diode (the other is blocking) and overcome 3 V (so 3.6 V total) before it can appear at the output. So that one will be (10-3.6)=6.4 V peak. From 0 V to 3.6 V, it is clipped. On the other half cycle it has to drop through the other diode, 0.6 V, and then experiences a 1/3 resistor divider, so it peaks at 1/3 * 9.4 V or about 3.1V. From 0 V to -0.6V, it is clipped. A double-bump with shoulders, kind of.

Comment: May I have reached the result with the arrangement I made?

Comment: @safak26 No, that's not right.

Comment: without calculating resistors. Can you draw the chart?